# Cucumber, Java: Step definition ignore in specific file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I've got a simple setup with Cucumber feature files and Java step definition files.

feature.feature -> StepDefinition.java -> PageObject.java

Specifically:

```
STEP:                              Step definition file:                          
Given I am logged in as ....    -> LoginSteps.java
And I am at the workspace       -> WorkspaceSteps.java
And I start a new application   -> WorkspaceSteps.java
And I accept                    -> AcceptPage.java  - does not work. 
- BUT:
And I accept                    -> AcceptPage.java  - DOES work
```

As shown above, I'm using three step defintion files here. And cucumber recognizes the step definitions in both files. But it doesn't even attempt to run the "And I accept" step when it's defined in the AcceptPage.java file. If I move it to the WorkspaceSteps.java file, it runs fine.

There are no complaints about missing step definitions. In fact, there are no error messages, just orange coloring of the test results.

IntelliJ Run window:

```
Test results                     4s462ms
- Feature: Complete application  4s462ms
- - Scenario: Budget             4s462ms
- - - And I accept               0ms
```

The .feature file:

```
Scenario: Budget
# Login/workspace
Given I am logged in as "12048746711"
And I am on the Workspace screen
And I start a new application
  
# Accept
And I accept
```

LoginSteps.java:

```
@Given("^I am logged in as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void iLogInWithId(String id) {
    login(createPersonInfo(id));
}
```

WorkspaceSteps.java

```
@Given("^And I am on the Workspace screen$")
public void iAmOnScreenWorkspace() {
    iAmOnWorkspace();
}

@Given("^I start a new application$")
public void startNewApplication() {
    workSpacePage.applyForLoan.click();
}
```

AcceptPage.java

```
@Given"^I accept$")
public void iAccept() {
    System.out.print("");
    acceptPage.iAccept.click();
}
```

The step pointing to the iAccept() method on the AcceptPage.java doesn't run. Even when I put a break point on the System.out.print() line and debug, it doesn't stop or even get there.

But If I move the entire iAccept() method into the WorkSpace.java file, everything works.

Any ideas?

Of course, I've invalidated IntelliJ's caches and restarted. I've even tried creating a brand new Steps file, containing a new step with a new name. It's the same: The cucumber test refuses to go anywhere except to the WorkspaceSteps.java file. This is starting to look completely idiotic, hillarious and absurd.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was really silly. For some reason, IntelliJ had removed the top package from the Glue in the configuration, and instead added specific packages. So, when a file not belonging to those packages was used, it was just ignored without further explanation. Deleting the specific packages and entering the top package solved the problem.